# Marker passar id ao setOnInfoWindowClickListener

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

Estou tentando passar o valor do marker para o setOnInfoWindowClickListener, mas não estou sabendo qual é a melhor maneira para isso, alguém pode me ajudar? Ele até passa um valor, mas não do loop, ou seja, não está passando o valor do marker por id. meu código.

Codigo completo

```
    private class MapaGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>  implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    // Lista onde vamos guardar os valores
    List<MapasController> ListaDeController = new ArrayList<MapasController>(0);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewMaps.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Por favor, aguarde...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        cx =  new Conexao();
        String jsonStr = cx.get(url);

        Log.d("Resposta: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                // De-serialize the JSON
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    MapasController mc = new MapasController();


                    mc.setLatitude(jsonObj.getDouble(TAG_LATITUDE));
                    mc.setLongitude(jsonObj.getDouble(TAG_LONGITUDE));

                    mc.setTitulo(jsonObj.getString(TAG_TITULO));
                    mc.setDescricao(jsonObj.getString(TAG_DESCRICAO));
                    mc.setId(jsonObj.getString(TAG_ID));
                    mc.setStatus(jsonObj.getString(TAG_STATUS));
                    mc.setData(jsonObj.getString(TAG_DATA));
                    mc.setUsuario(jsonObj.getString(TAG_USUARIO));
                    mc.setCategoria(jsonObj.getString(TAG_CATEGORIA));

                    // Adicionamos na lista
                    ListaDeController.add(mc);



                    Log.d ("", "get " + mc.getCategoria() + "Longitude " + mc.getLatitude() + " "  + jsonObj.getString(TAG_TITULO) );


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Error processing JSON", e);
            }


        } else {
            Log.e("Get: ", "Não foi possível obter quaisquer dados do url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Se o tamanho da lista fo maior que zero!
        if(ListaDeController.size() > 0){

            for(final MapasController mc  : ListaDeController){

                LatLng local = new LatLng(mc.getLatitude(), mc.getLongitude());

                // Seleciona o ícone de acordo com a categoria do mesmo

                Marker mapa =  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(local)
                        .title(mc.getTitulo())
                        .snippet(mc.getDescricao())
                        .draggable(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icone))

                );
                mMap.getCameraPosition();
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(local));
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(19), 2000, null); // animação zoom 10 com 2 segundos


            }



            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    Intent in = new Intent(ViewMaps.this, DescricaoMaps.class);

                    in.putExtra(TAG_ID, mc.getId());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TITULO, mc.getTitulo());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRICAO, mc.getDescricao());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_DATA, mc.getData());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_STATUS, mc.getStatus());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_USUARIO, mc.getUsuario());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CATEGORIA, mc.getCategoria());

                    ViewMaps.this.startActivity(in);


                }
            });

        }



        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}




@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;


    // se o mapa não está nulo , vamos carregar
    if (mMap != null) {
        new MapaGet().execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema, consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Coloquei antes o hasmap

```
 HashMap<String, String> markerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Depois no código passei o id do marker:

```
 String id = marker.getId();
            markerMap.put(id, mc.getId());
```

E por fim, fiz um get no  mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener e comparei o id do marker com o id do post.

```
if (mc.getId().equals(markerMap.get(marker.getId()))){
```

Resultado:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Se o tamanho da lista fo maior que zero!
        if(ListaDeController.size() > 0){

         //  for (int i = 0; i < ListaDeController.size(); i++){

            for(final MapasController mc  : ListaDeController){

              //  MapasController mc = new MapasController();
                LatLng local = new LatLng(mc.getLatitude(), mc.getLongitude());

                // Seleciona o ícone de acordo com a categoria do mesmo

                  Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(local)
                        .title(mc.getTitulo())
                        .snippet(mc.getDescricao())
                        .draggable(true)

                );

                mMap.getCameraPosition();
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(local));
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(19), 2000, null); // animação zoom 10 com 2 segundos

              //  int id = 0;
                //int id = Integer.parseInt(mc.getId());

                String id = marker.getId();
                markerMap.put(id, mc.getId());


            }

        }

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {


                Intent in = new Intent(ViewMaps.this, DescricaoMaps.class);


                for(final MapasController mc  : ListaDeController){

                    if (mc.getId().equals(markerMap.get(marker.getId()))){

                    in.putExtra(TAG_ID, mc.getId());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TITULO, mc.getTitulo());
                    in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRICAO, mc.getDescricao());
                    //  in.putExtra(TAG_DATA, mc.getData());
                    //  in.putExtra(TAG_STATUS, mc.getStatus());
                    //  in.putExtra(TAG_USUARIO, mc.getUsuario());
                    //  in.putExtra(TAG_CATEGORIA, mc.getCategoria());
                    Log.d("Passando parametro:", "Teste" + mc.getTitulo() + mc.getDescricao());
                    startActivity(in);
                    }

                }



            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma classe que extenda GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener

por exemplo

```
public class MyOnInfoWindowClickListener extends GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    private int mParametro = 0;

    public MyOnInfoWindowClickListener(int parametro) {
        this.mParametro = parametro;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
       //implementar o método, pode usar o mParametro aqui dentro

    }
}
```

e no setOnInfoWindowClickListener, basta criar uma instancia da classe

```
int id = 3;
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new MyOnInfoWindowClickListener(id))
```

espero ter ajudado!

[EDIT]

Tente isto

```
private class MapaGet ... {


  //...
  //seu codigo
  //

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      //...
      //...
      int id = 0;
      mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new MyOnInfoWindowClickListener(id, mc));
    }

    public class MyOnInfoWindowClickListener extends GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

        private int mParametro = 0;
        private MapasController mMapasController = null;

        public MyOnInfoWindowClickListener(int parametro, MapasController mapasController) {
            this.mParametro = parametro;
            this.mMapasController = mapasController;
        }

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
           //implementar o método, pode usar o mParametro aqui dentro

           MapasController mc = mMapasController;
           Intent in = new Intent(ViewMaps.this, DescricaoMaps.class);

              in.putExtra(TAG_ID, mc.getId());
              in.putExtra(TAG_TITULO, mc.getTitulo());
              in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRICAO, mc.getDescricao());
              in.putExtra(TAG_DATA, mc.getData());
              in.putExtra(TAG_STATUS, mc.getStatus());
              in.putExtra(TAG_USUARIO, mc.getUsuario());
              in.putExtra(TAG_CATEGORIA, mc.getCategoria());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu estou usando esse loop do marker dentro do onPostExecute, eu crio essa classe MyOnInfoWindowClickListener fora do loop já com o maker e depois chamo com um new Class() ?

Comment: Pode criar dentro da mesma classe, ou outra classe mesmo. Pode passar o MapasController mc, como parâmetro também.

Comment: Olá, estou com dificuldade para colocar a informação que você me passou no meu código, consegue me ajudar mais um pouco?

Comment: Opa, desculpa a demora.. aonde você está tentando colocar o código??

Comment: Olá, sem problemas, coloquei o código completo na pergunta, eu estou com dificuldade de criar essa classe que sugeriu, no meu código, na verdade queria aplicar o código isso mantendo a arquitetura que já tem no código

Comment: Editei a resposta, ao invés de implementar o listener na própria chamada do método, basta criar uma classe implementando o listener, e na chamada do método, você cria uma instancia da classe, passando quantos parâmetros forem necessários.

Comment: Puxa, fiz as mudanças e continua mostrando apenas 1 item..rs não sei onde estou errando..rs

Comment: Como assim apenas 1 item?  Não te entendi

Comment: então, preciso que cada marker passe seu próprio id para a próxima activity, mas só passa sempre 1 id, e é o primeiro.. posso clicar em quantos markers que for, que só vai no mesmo sempre. Mesmo com essas alterações que me disse, continua passando sempre o mesmo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43888/discussion-between-marco-giovanni-and-rubens-junior).